# How do I know what files should be gitignored?

Tags: git, github

I'm beginner in Open-Source and would like to know are there any guidelines for adding files to `.gitignore`?

Comment: You put in there whatever you want to ignore...

Comment: What is you project (android, ios, php, python ... )? each framework has an default gitignore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the files you do not want in your git repository in the [.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file.

These are typically:

- Easy to generate files
- Intermediate (build) files
- Large binaries (e.g. documentation), that are also available elsewhere (on your companies servers)
- Files containing sensitive information (like passwords)
- Files of external dependencies (especially when using a dependency manager to retrieve their exact version)